# Unhandled Exception Error

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

I am experiencing an `unhandled exception` within `xutility`

```
if (_Myproxy != 0)
    {   // proxy allocated, drain it
    _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

    for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
        *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
        (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0;  <------- unhandled exception here
    _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
}
```

I do not have control over `xutility`.  This `unhandled exception` train stems from

```
std::string BinarySearchFile::readT(long filePointerLocation, long sizeOfData) 
{
     try{
          if(binary_search_file){
              std::string data;
              binary_search_file.seekp(filePointerLocation);
              binary_search_file.seekg(filePointerLocation);
              binary_search_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data), sizeOfData);

              return data;  <------- branch into xutility and subsequent unhandled exception

          }else if(binary_search_file.fail()){
              throw CustomException("Attempt to read attribute error");
          }

     }
     catch(CustomException &custom_exception){  // Using custom exception class
          std::cout << custom_exception.what() << std::endl;
     }

}
```

Normally, the `return` would proceed to

```
std::string BinarySearchFile::read_data(long filePointerLocation, long sizeOfData){
    return readT(filePointerLocation, sizeOfData);
}
```

And subsequently back to the original call

```
attributeValue = data_file->read_data(index, size);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Unhandled exception" is a pretty hopeless diagnostic, you'll need to tell what you know about it.  The debugger shows you the details about the exception.  In general, avoid thinking this has anything to do with xutility, your program corrupting the heap is the standard explanation.

Comment: From what I have posted (code) above, what do you think would be corrupting the heap?  I am simply reading binary data into `std::string` and returning it back to the caller.

Comment: You mangled memory somewhere. Where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` string is empty when you try to read into it. That will corrupt memory somewhere.

You should add `data.resize(sizeOfData)` to allocate space, and then read into its buffer

```
binary_search_file.read(&data[0], sizeOfData);
                             ^^^
```

not into the string object itself.

Comment: Correct. OP is treating `data` as some ready-made collection of bytes, but it is not. It is a complex object that in fact happens to internally and indirectly "contain" no bytes whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, this works but not as intended. I will have to ask another question related to why the binary data read is incorrect.  I wrote to the file "packard (three trailing spaces)" using `binary_search_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&attribute), attribute.length() * 2);` but received back via `binary_search_file.read(&data[0], sizeOfData);`XXX packard   XXX` where X is undesired data.