# OpenProcess the handle is invalid. CloseHandle not work

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I don't know what something wrong with my code. i already put condition when the handle is invalid. it will CloseHandle. but it seems not work. this code trying to get processName. when i input exist PID. it return the processName. opposite when i  input doesn't exist PID like **10000**. it return handle is invalid. and Error Exception throw. but in my code i already put condition when invalid. it will Close Handle.

```
    std::wstring GetProcessNameById(DWORD i_processId)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, i_processId);
    if (hProcess != NULL)
    {
        wchar_t processFilePath[MAX_PATH];
        if (GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, processFilePath, MAX_PATH))
        {
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            wchar_t *processFileName = PathFindFileNameW(processFilePath);
            return processFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            SystemErrorMessage();
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        SystemErrorMessage();
    }
}

int main()
{
std::wcout << GetProcessNameById(10000);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RbMm thats what i think if success handle it will return processName. but when failed. i dont put return to wstring. maybe that the case.

Comment: i not note at begin that your function return `wstring` - as result in `return processFileName;` was implicit conversion. but your logic with `CloseHandle` of course wrong. you need only single call `CloseHandle` in case it not zero

Comment: @RbMm i don't know what u means anyway. i remove else brace. it still same result. and as i think if i remove inside else brace. how i can know if it return invalid handle.

Comment: `OpenProcess` return or 0 or valid handle. and this handle have no protect from close attribute at begin. `CloseHandle` is of course work correct. not closehandle not work. your code not work

Comment: @RbMm so 0 is not same NULL in c++?

Comment: 0 and NULL of course the same. and so what ?

Comment: @RbMm cause. i dont get u said not closehandle not work. your code not work.

Comment: in your code 3 calls CloseHandle - begin from remove 2 of it. and than use debugger

Comment: Don't change the question after an answer to *that* question has been submitted. If you have a new question, click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @RbMm is it already right with the logic if? when i use debugger it point me to std::wcout line

Comment: @IInspectable i don't mean to change question. but, too fix. if i keep put new try code. its can?

Comment: no, in your concrete code logic is wrong. and simply use debugger - for step by step this small function

Comment: @RbMm so how suppose to be? i dont get sense u talking with the clue. i think to easy for u fix if logic. cause only api only in there. its more easy to make understand if u put at least code.

Comment: @RbMm cause, word is verbal. it has many meaning dependent whos talk that.

Comment: in your code must be only **one** CloseHandle call. and use debugger

Comment: @RbMm i understand now, i think the code should like this now. but when i debug it point me to ` *_Pnext != nullptr; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)` from xutulity

Comment: Stop changing the question in a way that invalidates already posted answers. If you have a new question, you know what to do. I rolled back the changes, for the 3rd time now.

Comment: @RbMm i get error like this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038954/unhandled-exception-error. its like return failure here.

Comment: That's a follow-up question. That bug only manifests itself, once you fix the bug this question is asking about. It is caused by the fact, that not all control paths in your function return a value. Your compiler told you about this already. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

A compact version of your code makes the bug obvious:

```
if (hProcess != NULL)
{
    // Left out for brevity
}
else 
{
    // Here, hProcess is NULL
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    SystemErrorMessage();
}
```

In essence, this is calling `CloseHandle(NULL);`, presumably setting the thread's last error code to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. `SystemErrorMessage()` probably blindly calls `GetLastError` (without evaluating whether it should), and throws an exception if the value returned is anything other than `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

To fix this, you need to fix the logic bug (remove the call to `CloseHandle` in the `else` branch, in which you *know* `hProcess` to be invalid). When done, rework your entire error handling. It won't work reliably. You cannot blindly call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx), anytime an API call failed. When done with that, study the [RAII idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), so that you won't have to write manual cleanup code, like you would have to do with C.

Comment: but i think my logic is right. as description OpenProcess return value. from msdn is **If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the specified process.

If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.**

Comment: i don't know to point me to if thread. if u think my logic is wrong. i just make opposite if condition but still same `if (hProcess == NULL) {} else {}`

Comment: inside else brace is getprocessname.

Comment: @IInspectable please add a short description to WHY GetLastError does not work ubiquitiously for all win32 api.

Comment: @joh If you want the error code you must call GetLastError **immediately** after the call fails. Any intervening call may change the error code.

Comment: Failure is neither required nor sufficient. Some APIs set the last error code in case of success (e.g. [CreateMutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw)), others don't set it at all, even when they fail (like most/all of the GDI calls). That's what the documentation says: *"You should call the GetLastError function **immediately** when **a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data**."* You will have to consult the documentation for each and every API call to find that information.